# opendir and closedir and readdir missing from the MSDN documentation

Tags: c, file-io, directory, msdn

I have seen people using opendir(), closedir() & readdir() but I could not find MSDN documentation around it.

Why is it so? Are these APIs undocumented APIs?

Should we not use them because they are unreliable and their support can be removed by Microsoft anytime?

Comment: These functions are specific to Linux/Unix like operating systems. On Windows look for FindFirstFile, FindNextFile etc.

Comment: These functions are defined in POSIX. So I assume you are looking in ported code, so the program uses some libraries which translate POSIX to windows API.

Comment: These APIs have been around longer than Microsoft!